# Insert PDF file on every other page automatically using script

Tags: powershell, pdf, vbscript, merge, pdftk

I was wondering if this is possible with pdftk on command line, or if not pdftk, is there another tool available?

I would like to accomplish this: A pdf file is generated (report cards) from our system. 1 page per student but multiple students may be included in a single pdf. I want to automatically insert a static back side to the pdf inserting this in between every page, then re-save the pdf to the same name. This would allow our users to then print this 2-sided with the report card on front side, and the static back on the back.

The tricky part is that the back side is different depending on the grade level and language (English or Spanish) of the report card. Grade level and language can be detected by looking in a standard place on the front side of the report card.

Based on my research, it sounds like pdftk might be able to do this with some scripting, however I am not sure. It'd be great if I could do this with maybe a regular .bat file, a vbscript, or with powershell.

Do I need to split out the pdf into individual files, and then merge them together that way?Could this be accomplished? Thank you in advance.

Additional information added 1/28/18. Maybe I should have explained better: I need to write a script that will take the following pdf, insert pages as appropriate, then create a new pdf and save.

So the original multi-page pdf will be like this as an example:

1A. Grade 1 English
2A. Grade 1 English
3A. Grade 2 English
4A. Grade 2 Spanish
5A. Grade 2 English

Then I would have single page PDF files for the appropriate grace and language which I would want inserted as a back side like this:

1A. Grade 1 English
1B. Grade 1 English back
2A. Grade 1 English
2B. Grade 1 English back
3A. Grade 2 English
3B. Grade 2 English back
4A. Grade 2 Spanish
4B. Grade 2 Spanish back
5A. Grade 2 English
5B. Grade 2 English back

To determine the grade and the language, I need to look for data in a specific location on the original pdf.

Can this be accomplished with pdftk or another tool? It seems that pdftk can only merge PDF files, not look for content on a pdf to determine which backside to use.

Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Probably you would get better answers to this in a forum related with pdftk.

Comment: Any suggestions on where to ask? I looked for other forums.

Comment: You're question is a little too unspecific for SO. Did you actually *try* doing this with pdftk already? Did something not work? Did you get an error? What were the differences between expected and actual result?

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I should have explained better. I edited my original question.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

1) Obvious thing first, you already said that: split your original multipage pdf into single pages with pdftk using command: pdftk original.pdf burst . Check out man page for details https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/

2) This maybe tricky but it seems like a solution. When I had to insert single pages into pdf articles (when working on digitization project) I used imagemagick to generate those single pages (they containted article's author name, title etc.). Maybe you could try to use imagemagick to recognize whether report card is English or Spanish (or whatever other language) by checking single pixel color. I mean, if they have standard unchanging fragments, you can just pick a pixel which is e.g. always black on English report card and always white on Spanish report card. Just an idea.

You try to check the color of a pixel with something like that:

```
convert report.pdf: -format '%[pixel:p{40,30}]' info:-
```

Details of syntax: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#extract - look for "Extracting a Specific Color" section.

3) Now you can join report cards with static back side with 'pdftk cat output' command. Something like:

```
pdftk 1A.pdf 1B.pdf 2A.pdf 2B.pdf 3A.pdf 3B.pdf cat output merged.pdf
```

Again you can check details at https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/  (look for "cat [ < page ranges > ]" )

Also some examples of using pdftk cat from documentation:

> Join in1.pdf and in2.pdf into a new PDF, out1.pdf
>
> pdftk in1.pdf in2.pdf cat output out1.pdf
>
> or (using handles):
>
> pdftk A=in1.pdf B=in2.pdf cat A B output out1.pdf
>
> or (using wildcards):
>
> pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf

Hope this helps